# Error al realizar pruebas con Jest

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, jest

Tengo un proyecto en donde necesito hacer pruebas unitarias, inicio el proyecto sin problemas y una vez corro el Jest, me sale:

```
  message: 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo',
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'Unknown',
        servers: Map(1) { 'mongo:27018' => [ServerDescription] },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
      }
```

El archivo de conexión de base de datos es:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27018/docker-node-mongo',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

No sé a que se debe, he intentando de todo pero el error es solo en los test, cuando corro el proyecto funciona perfecto hace los `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` a base de datos sin problema.

Comment: Por favor agrega el test en donde lo estás usando y las configuraciones que hayas hecho